# Event listener's anonymous function

Tags: javascript, parameters, addeventlistener

Why does the following anonymous JS function has "e" as parameter? I get that it's the event but how was it saved? there is no mention of this "e" anywhere but in this event listener and in the handler that it uses.

```
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
```

Comment: `e` is a parameter that's is passed by the caller function when the event is fired. Try to think that somewhere there's a place that has all the functions attached to the `keyup` event in the `body` element. Whenever this events fires, this function does something like `callback(eventFired)`.

Comment: Ok so there is something like a default or universal library at at work here and the function called "instead of" that anonymous one needs this argument, did i get it right ?

Comment: It's the browser that your code is running on that is responsible of taking care of that. It's not like, in this case, "it needs" that one argument. It's up to you to use it or not. The caller will add any argument it wants to the callback function (in this case, the `event` one), so you can use it by placing a parameter in the function you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that that anonymous function is called the moment a `keyup` event occurs.  The anonymous function says, "Hey, when you call me, be sure to give me an argument."  So, when the `keyup` event happens, the browser will call that anonymous function with an argument, which will be the event object.  The event object is created the moment the event occurs.

Comment: The presence of a named parameter doesn't change the behaviour of the browser. The event object will always be passed to the handler.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification.  I am aware of that, however I wanted to leave the technical noise out of my response in order to stay focused on what the question author was asking.

Comment: Well thank you both that makes things very clear to me, so this means it doesnt have to be "e", i can use any placeholder i like right ?

Comment: @poolmatho — It's a variable name for a function argument, just like any other.

Answer (score 0):

The method `addAventListener` takes a function as its input, and then calls this function with an event-object whenever the event occurs.

Added a simple example to illustrate this.

```js
function EventCreator() {
  var listeners = [];
  var counter = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    counter++;
    listeners.forEach(function(listener) {
      listener(counter);
    });
  }, 1000);

  this.addListener = function(listener) {
    listeners.push(listener);
  };
}

var eventCreator = new EventCreator();

eventCreator.addListener(function(e) {
  console.log("An event has occured: ", e);
});
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Thanks dude but just a question, why isnt the addlistener function inside of the set interval function ? doesnt it need to run everytime this runs ?

Comment: The add listener function just appends a listener to a list. And when an event happens you go through the list of listeners and call them one by one with the new event (which in this example is counter). The function that is sent in as a parameter to addListener is not called at once, it is stored int he list till the event happens, and then it is called.